# What is the risk in adding unknown PPAs?

Tags: ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are “PPA's” safe to add to my system, and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Whenever I add a new repository PPA, I get a warning asking me if i trust it. Ubuntu doesn't catch any virus or malware since it asks password for each and everything.

So, the question is: What is the risk in adding unknown PPAs?