# Is it safe to install applications from PPAs?

Tags: 12.04, security, ppa, cinnamon, mate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are “PPA's” safe to add to my system, and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)
>   [What is the risk in adding an unknown PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84404/what-is-the-risk-in-adding-an-unknown-ppa)

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and would like, for example, to install the MATE and Cinnamon graphical interfaces. Of course, I'll need to add two PPA's to my system, in order to install these packages.

So, first of all, is it safe to install packages from PPA's (for example: MATE and Cinnamon)?

Once installed, can these packages (including package upgrades) conflict with the operating system?